# How to change the directory of pytest logs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

How do I change the directory for my pytest logs?

I currently have a **pytest.ini** file where the file name of the logs is called **pytest.log** every time I run my pytest code. It will just create a new "pytest.log" every time I run overwriting the previous log in the **main folder** but I want it inside the **logs** folder. I'm still new to pytest and logging so I'm not familiar on how to add all pytest.log files to a specific logs folder. This is what the folder structure looks like.

current:

```
 -- main folder 
    - pytest.ini
    - pytest.log
    -- logs
```

what I want:

```
 -- main folder 
    - pytest.ini
    -- logs
       - pytest.log
```

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#confval-log_file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
log_file = logs/pytest.log
```